# MEAN stack and socket.io, expressions evaluate too fast

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, mean-stack

I'm having a hard time using angular and socket.io. 
When accessing a page I'm connecting to the server (Node.js) using socket.io. The server pulls data from mongoDB, then sends the data back to the client-side written in angular, which in turn should display the data using `ng-repeat`.

`admin.hjs`:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
   <H1>Admin</H1>
   {{mc.msgs.length}}
   {{mc.msgs}}
   <div ng-repeat="msg in mc.msgs">
       {{msg.name}}
   </div>
</body>
```

`app.js`:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('msgsSystem', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function(){
    var ctr = this;
    ctr.msgs = [];
    var socket = io.connect();
    //when receiving the msgs from the server
    socket.on('getMsgs', function(data){
        ctr.msgs = data;
        console.log('gotMsgs');
        console.log(ctr.msgs.length);
    });
  });
})();
```

When accessing the page I see that `{{mc.msgs.length}} {{mc.msgs}}` getting evaluated to `0 []`, but in the console `gotMsgs 6`. My guess is that the page is rendering before the response comes back from the server.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think the problem is that the socket callback doesn't execute in an angular scope so while the variables have changed, angular doesn't know about it and doesn't update your display.

Comment: Put a callback function inside socket.on() that compiles your message template and pass the data as a parameter. This way, it will only be populated once the 'getMsgs' data is received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJs does not work properly if you update scope variables in asynchronous methods (sockets, ajax). `$scope.$apply()` solves this issue.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.msgs = [];
    var socket = io.connect();
    //when receiving the msgs from the server
    socket.on('getMsgs', function(data){
        $scope.msgs = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. I got away with only passing $scope as the callback parameter and then calling $scope.apply()